# Can this product be converted into a summation?

Tags: summation, products

Is there any way this product can be converted into a summation?
$$\prod_{p=1}^L (x-p)$$
I know that there is a way because I remember seeing it in a homework for school.

Comment: if the p was constant, it would be as simple as the binomial theorem.

Comment: See "[signed Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)"

Comment: If $(x)_L$ is the "falling factorial," then this is $(x-1)_L$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found a page that wasn't the same question, but it helped my find an answer.
[Change from product to sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336271/change-from-product-to-sum)
It shows that the product of $f(x)$ is equal to $e$ raised to the sum of ln(abs(f(x))) multiplied by negative one raised to the ceiling of $x$ (The abs of the function and the negative one raised to the ceiling of $x$ is to get rid of the ln of negative numbers)

Comment: Are you sure $x-p$ is not negative?

Comment: @Siong good point, I just edited my answer to include that